# Blocking stray RF with diamagnetic materials?

Tags: current, rf

In my ham shack there is a wire that runs for 4 feet from my transmitter to
the RF ground and I wish to stop it from radiating as much as possible.
All of the normal precautions are in place but I enjoy going over the top with this kind of thing.  I am curious if a diamagnetic material could be used to block stray RF. For instance, running the ground wire through a tube of Pyrolytic carbon or Bismuth or another diamagnetic substance.

Comment: What effects do you think this would have on the electric and magnetic fields surrounding the wire?

Comment: Ideally your ground wire should not have any currents it, just making sure all the things in the box are closed off.

Answer (score 1):

Ferrite is commonly used to absorb RF.  With the right formulation, it can appear to have the same impedance as free space, except that that RF waves are absorbed rather than continuing to propagate.  Ferrite is one of the two common means to make anachoic RF chambers, with the other being cones.  Often both ferrite and cones are used together to cover a broader frequency range.

Once you see the cost of ferrite though, you may want to rethink your strategy.

Comment: I use ferrites and I understand that, owing to their high magnetic permeability, they concentrate magnetic fields within themselves. I guess I'm thinking of diamagnetic materials of acting as an anti-ferrite.

Comment: @Cargo: I don't understand what you are trying to do then.  Ferrite surrounding the wire would absorb RF emissions from it, which I thought you were asking about.  The other approach is a shield, but it's difficult to ensure the shield doesn't just pick up and re-radiate the RF energy.

Comment: I was thinking that